# Parametric modelling of customer lifetime value using survival (Cox) analysis

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, marketing

I have half a year long data of purchases in e-commerce site (100K purchases by 60K customers). In simplest A/B testing framework random customers got a discount on the next purchase after order completion ( `disc` = 0/1 below). I want to estimate to what extent `disc` influenced an interval between orders (`diff`).

Following KISS principle, I just drop all 1-time customers and regress ln(`diff`) on `disc`, but don't observe the effect at all. I have two obvious problems:

1. data is very censored, 60% of customers appeared only once
2. selection bias - frequent buyers had more chances to get a discount

To address (1), I turn to Cox-model  `coxph(Surv(diff, event) ~ disc + cluster(customer_id))`  (and observe the effect!), but can't figure out whether it is the best method to handle multiple failure times(purchases) per customer. For (2), I'm thinking of introducing lagged `diff`, but don't know how to do it in a censored case.

There were number of relevant discussions ([RFM & customer lifetime value modeling in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20463/rfm-customer-lifetime-value-modeling-in-r) , 
[Survival Analysis with Multiple Events](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39010/survival-analysis-with-multiple-events)), but I fail to find a solution for my problems. There is also BTYD package, but it's not parametric. Guess this is very standard question, but can't find a step-by-step (CrossValidated) guide

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstand, but why not compare Kaplan-Meier curves of the two groups. Also, why parametric (specifically Cox)?

Comment: I want to use effect size to calculate the change of customer lifetime value. If our discount increases median purchase rate by large enough % we could possibly extend this campaign
I thought only Cox can give me such information more or less precisely, but may be wrong

Comment: Lots of method are listed here - http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html . I guess my case is "Recurrent event data". Using coxph + cluster gives me the Anderson-Gill model, but I still doubt that this is my case

Comment: If you are interested in estimating the impact of covariates on CLV you might want to have a look at the R package CLVTools. Here is tutorial on how to analyze the transaction of an apparel retailer: https://www.clvtools.com/articles/CLVTools.html